# make bottom edge of button 1 and top edge of button 2 placed under button 1 vertically centre align?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am developing an ios application in xcode 5.1 using story boards for ios 7.1. I have 2 buttons placed one on top of the other. Take for instance button "done" is top and button "nest page" is below button "done". There is no space between bottom edge of button "done" and top edge of button "nest page". I would like to vertically centre align both the buttons on the right side of the screen.

[image]

Comment: You can upload your image in http://tinypic.com/ and send the link

Comment: So you want to add the space between them

Comment: I would like to vertically centre align both the buttons on the right side of the screen.

Comment: So you can do it with `.xib` file or in `storyboard`

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi storyboard

Comment: So you can positioned them easily with `storyboard`. Where is the problem?

Comment: I am getting confused on the type of constraints that has to be implmented

Comment: what constraints, if you drag the button, a *blue* center vertical line will be shown if the two buttons are centrally vertical.

Comment: what yo do after that?

Comment: just press control and drag from button1 to button2 and select vertical alignment, done.

Comment: They are now centrally aligned. Now you can do whatever you want

Comment: vertical alignment option is not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the two buttons into another UIView. Center that wrapper view vertically and make it match the size of the two buttons.

Like it is done in the following screenshot. Note that I expanded the yellow wrapper view to the left side so you can see how this is supposed to work. You don't want to do this in your app.

[image]